# I tried to make a balance command in discord.py but it didn't worked and gives unexpected errors

Tags: python, discord.py, command

I was trying to make a balance checking command for my bot but when I tried it, it doesn't works the other command of bot works but not the bal command.

Changes made : defined user and added {} to json file.

Also this is the new error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 21, in balance
    await open_account(ctx.author)
  File "main.py", line 36, in open_account
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]=0
KeyError: '774126913664188416'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "/home/dcoder/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/project-e8xowoWm-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: '774126913664188416'
```

Code below :

```py
import discord
import discord.ext
import webserver
import json
from webserver import keep_alive
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('{0.user}'.format(client) , 'is now online')
  await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="with pokemons"))

@client.command(name='fact')
async def facts(ctx):
  await ctx.send("elon musk is the richest person in world")

@client.command(name='bal')
async def balance(ctx):
  await open_account(ctx.author)
  users = await get_bank_data()
  wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]
  em = discord.Embed(title = f"{ctx.author}'s balance",color = discord.Color.blue())
  em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
  
  await ctx.send(embed = em)

  
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()
    
    if str(user.id) in users:
      return False
    else:
      users[str(user.id)]["wallet"]=0
      
    with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
      users = json.dump(users,f)
      return True

async def get_bank_data():
  with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
    
  return users

keep_alive()
client.run('token')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code contains an error at one point. You forgot to define the `user`. The following code would be correct for the command:

```py
@client.command()
async def balance(ctx):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    user = ctx.author # Defined user
    users = await get_bank_data()
    wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] # We need the user here
    em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author}'s balance", color=discord.Color.blue())
    em.add_field(name="Wallet balance", value=wallet_amt)

    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

Your `async` events are not wrong in themselves, but we don't need to define `user` there, it doesn`t do any good. So the correct thing would be:

```py
async def open_account(user):
    users = await get_bank_data()

    if str(user.id) in users:
        return False
    else:
        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0

    with open("mainbank.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(users, f)
    return True
```

Please make sure that your JSON file looks like this:

```py
{}
```

***To sum it up:***

- We defined `user` as it is needed
- Removed unnecessary/useless definitions

Comment: ok but my bot still do not shows up the message....

Comment: What error comes up? Also please do not delete your comments...

Comment: i deleted because i accidentally sent half written comment sorry lol

Comment: now i edited my post i edited that what changes i made and i edited the error

Comment: `KeyError` means that the user does not exist in the JSON. Open it and have a look.

Comment: so that's means something is wrong with my ide? ;-;

Comment: It means that the user ID is not in the JSON. Try to use a command that adds a value to the JSON or insert the following: `{"774126913664188416": {"wallet": 1}}` - Note that this is just to test if the JSON works. I guess you have other commands that also work with your JSON or insert values into it.